# Android WebView viewport overflow on text searching

Tags: android, android-webview, zooming

I have an activity with a simple **WebView**. Its content fits the screen width.

But when I run `findAllAsync()` command to highlight some text in the content the component width **overflows** the screen.
If I search the second time the overflow is gone, the third time - appears again and so on.

It also happens with `findNext()`.

I tried different combinations of parameters related to zooming but didn't succeed.
(`setBuiltInZoomControls(), setLayoutAlgorithm(), setSupportZoom(), setUseWideViewPort(), setLoadWithOverviewMode(), setOverScrollMode(), setInitialScale()`)

**Screen:**

[image]

At the bottom is the horizontal scrollbar showing the page overflows the screen.

**My code:**

```
String webContent = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) sb.append(i + "<br>");

sb.insert(0, "<div id='content' style='border: 4px solid #f00'>");
sb.append("</div>");
webContent = sb.toString();

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", webContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Also if I add `onScaleChanged()` method to the `WebViewClient` it shows that when Also if I add `onScaleChanged()` method to the `WebViewClient` it shows that when I incrementally search the text the page/WebView changes its scale, for example **from 1.59 to 1.64** and then **from 1.64 to 1.59**.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
    Fun.logd("-- onScaleChanged: " + oldScale + "; " + newScale);
    super.onScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale);
  }
});
```

Does somebody know if that could be resolved?

Thanks.